# UnsupportedOperationException on ByteBuffer.asCharArray().array()

Tags: java, nio, java-6

Could someone be so kind to explain why on the following line I have UnsupportedOperationException?

> System.out.println(ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[] {'t', 'e', 's', 't', '\n'}).asCharBuffer().array());

Answer (score 3):

The asCharBuffer doesn't wrap a `char[]` so you cannot obtain its `array()`

It appears what you are trying to do is.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("test\n".toCharArray()));
```

Comment: Actually I'm reading FileChannel with ByteBuffer (know for sure it is text file) and would like to have CharBuffer from ByteBuffer. If I cannot do it, what is the reason to have the method? And second question how to do it in a right way? Thank you.

Comment: When you build a CharBuffer which is a wrapper for an `char[]` you can use `array()` to get the original array you built the buffer from.

Comment: Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936275/fast-bytebuffer-to-charbuffer-or-char ?

Comment: Note, you have the problem that you must read a whole number of characters, which can be tricky if you have a multi-byte character encoding, unless you read everything before decoding.

Answer (score 3):

Did you read the Javadoc for [`CharBuffer.array()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html#array%28%29)?

Not all `CharBuffer`s are backed by a `char[]`.  `ByteBuffer.asCharBuffer()` returns a *view* of the `ByteBuffer` as a `CharBuffer`, so its result is backed by a `byte[]`.

`array()` only returns the `char[]` that actually backs the buffer, and if none exists, it throws a UOE.  The closest alternative you'll be able to get is something like

```
char[] result = new char[charBuf.remaining()];
charBuf.get(result);
```