# How to convert a ByteBuffer to long[] in Java

Tags: java, nio

Can someone please let me know how to convert a a ByteBuffer into a long[]?

I had a long[] to begin with, which I converted to a ByteBuffer using the following piece of code:

---

```
byte[] convertToByteArray(long[] data) {
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(data.length * 8);;
    LongBuffer longBuffer = byteBuffer.asLongBuffer();
    longBuffer.put(data);
    return byteBuffer.array();
}
```

---

I would now like to do the reverse, and write a few tests comparing the various arrays before and after conversion.

I tried the following, but it fails with an NPE on JDK 1.6.0_26:

---

```
long[] convertToLongArray(byte[] bArray) {
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bArray);
    LongBuffer longBuffer = byteBuffer.asLongBuffer();
    return longBuffer.array();
}
```

---

Regards,
Roshan

Comment: What does the NPE stacktrace say? It's often helpful to give enough information, if you have a problem.

Comment: Really weird that you put the data in `longBuffer` and returned `byteBuffer.array()` and yet you think that you got the proper output in the first case.

Comment: @R.J The ByteBuffer should act as a backing buffer, with the LongBuffer being only a view to it, so the code should be fine. He's just offloading the operation of converting long to 8 bytes to the LongBuffer.

Comment: @Kayaman - Thanks! I got that.:)

Comment: @Roshan - Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11761826/2024761). Since your LongBuffer doesn't have a backing `long[]` it'll throw the UOE.

Comment: @RJ, sorry, I mentioned NPE. It was an oversight in drafting the question. Yes, it did throw UnsupportedOperationException in absence of the backing long[].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on my side it throws

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.nio.LongBuffer.array(LongBuffer.java:994)
    at test.convertToLongArray(test.java:11)
    at test.main(test.java:15)
```

It does that because the instance returned by `byteBuffer.asLongBuffer()` call is a `ByteBufferAsLongBufferL` or `ByteBufferAsLongBufferB` class (depending on the indianess). 
Both of these 2 classes are sub-classes of LongBuffer and inside the constructor call `super` constructor is called without the *long array* parameter.

As @Kayaman mentioned, these are only views for the byte array from ByteBuffer.

Below is the super constructor called from the `ByteBufferAsLongBufferL` constructor. Notice the `null` parameter.

```
LongBuffer(int mark, int pos, int lim, int cap) { // package-private
    this(mark, pos, lim, cap, null, 0);
}
```

The best option is to do this:

```
long[] convertToLongArray(byte[] bArray) {
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bArray);
    LongBuffer longBuffer = byteBuffer.asLongBuffer();
    long l[] = new long[longBuffer.capacity()];
    longBuffer.get(l);
    return l;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just the solution I was looking for. Missed LongBuffer#get(long[]).